# memcache container: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:11211: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, memcached

I am having problems setting up memcached on my docker. I get an error when I run: ***docker run --name=memcache -p 11211:11211 -d memcached memcached -m 128***

This is the error that comes after running the command above

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint memcache (9f4bd30f7253ee185f6a160ef8e89d3f3c2d46f0361ec15f11a6975477c19430): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:11211: bind: address already in use.
```

In the end it says the port chosen is taken already. So to confirm that memcached doesn't listen on any ports I ran "**docker ps -a**", and this was the output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
116acff4b1aa        memcached            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago      Created                                    memcache
a4e1a6168bca        staticwebserver:v3   "/init.sh"               2 weeks ago         Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:8002->80/tcp   lucid_mccarthy
a27174f8a988        staticwebserver:v3   "/init.sh"               2 weeks ago         Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp   thirsty_shockley
```

As I can't see that the container(memcached) listens to any ports I wanted to see what process is already listening on port 11211. So I ran **netstat -pna | grep 11211**

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5703/memcached
```

Here I am confused, does memcached work? Or is something wrong?

I tried to kill the deamon, but it pops up again the second I kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running an instance of memcached outside of a container on the same port. You'll need to either stop that outside instance, or pick a different port to publish n the host. For stopping the outside instance, that depends on how you've been starting it, perhaps it's in systemd. You can work from the process id and look for parent pids until you find what's starting it, or pull up the process tree with `ps axjf`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out by looking at the process tree.